# How to setup Paystack in a laravel, vuejs application

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Please I need help, I can setup Paystack on Laravel with laravel blade, but am having problem when integrating Paystack with Laravel and Vuejs. Vue communicate via api endpoint. So I need help on how to set it up properly.

Comment: Post code and a specific question that can be answered.I really don't mean to be rude in any way - but asking a "good" question will help you get better responses. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try using this package vue-paystack.

Do `npm install vue vue-paystack --save`

Read the docs here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-paystack